# Perl print syntax not working when run on browser CGI

Tags: perl, browser, command-line, cgi

`print` syntax not working after `my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, "username", "password");` has been called. But when I put print syntax on the top of `my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, "username", "password");` `print` work properly. This case happen when I run this code through browser using CGI and when I run this code in command-line both work properly.

Here are the code:

```
#!"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe"
use CGI qw(:standard);
use DBI;
use JSON;

print header("application/json");

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=webservices;host=localhost;port=3306";

print "test"; #work properly
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, "root", "bukanjombloboy");
print "test"; #not working    

my $result = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM news");
$result->execute();

my $json_text = to_json($result->fetchall_arrayref());
print $json_text;

$dbh->disconnect();
```

Sorry for my bad English, thanks anyway.

Comment: try checking for errors in your connect call: `connect($dsn, "root", "...", {RaiseError => 1}) or die $DBI::errstr;`

Comment: ...and I'd recommend creating a new user specific to the db, instead of using root, particularly for a web service.

Comment: _Not working_ is not the very best problem description. Do you get a 500 error or simply no output on client side? Did you have a look at your webserver's error.log? What's in there?

Comment: `my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, "root", "bukanjombloboy", {RaiseError => 1}) or die $DBI::errstr;` I try this but still not working.

Comment: @PerlDuck there is no output on the page and no error given in webserver's error.log

Comment: @PerlDuck I think I found the problem. I checked error.log and I found this `install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load 'C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.xs.dll' for module DBD::mysql: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.` what probably cause this problem ? I have checked MySQL.xs.dll

Answer (score 0):

It could be a issue with the EOL, in the line:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect ($dsn, "root", "bukanjombloboy");
```

Check all your EOL are equal in all lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
The problem is APACHE webserver doesn't have permission to access the library so I have to run XAMPP on administrator mode.